# Line up the column position and corresponding values in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops

Orignial data format says row 1 is (1:20 3:25 5:24 9:20).

I am tring to convert the original data set to dataframe using python pandas or any other way in python.
I split the original data set into two list sample attribute list and Sample_value list.

```
sample_attribute
[[1,3,5,9],[3,5,7,10],[1,4,8,10]]
sample_value
[[20,25,24,20],[16,20,24,21],[12,20,24,17]

The perspective data frame should look like

Column: 1  2  3  4  5  6 7  8  9  10 
row 1:  20 0  25 0  24 0 0  0  20  0
row 2:  0  0  16 0  20 0 24 0  0  21
row 3:  12 0  0  20  0 0  0 24 0  17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure resembles a dictionary. You can convert it to a Python dictionary and then use pandas built-in from_dict method:

```
import pandas as pd    

sample_attribute = [[1,3,5,9],[3,5,7,10],[1,4,8,10]]
sample_value = [[20,25,24,20],[16,20,24,21],[12,20,24,17]]

# store sample in list of dictionaries
sample = [dict(zip(keys, values)) for keys, values in zip(sample_attribute,sample_value)]

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(sample)

# add columns without values
df = df.reindex(range(df.columns.min(),df.columns.max()+1),axis=1)

# replace NAN with zero
df = df.fillna(0)
```